# Создание триггера

Tags: mysql, sql

Создаю 2 триггера, первый выполняется успешно, второй выдает ошибку:
    #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

**Trigger 1:**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `hek`.`InsertCommentToUser`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `hek`.`InsertCommentToUser` AFTER INSERT ON `hek`.`commenttousers`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   INSERT INTO log Set 
   LogTime = NEW.CommentToUsersTime, 
   LogIdNote = NEW.idCommentToUsers, 
   LogName = NEW.CommentToUsersComment,
   LogType = 6,
   LogIdUser = NEW.CommentToUsersIdUser;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Trigger 2:**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `hek`.`CreatePhotoAlbumUser`;
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER `CreatePhotoAlbumUser` AFTER INSERT ON `hek`.`users`  
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
   INSERT INTO usersalbums Set   
   UsersAlbumsName = 'Diplomas, awards, certificates',   
   UsersAlbumsTime = NEW.UsersTime,   
   UsersAlbumsType = 1,  
   UsersAlbumsIdToUser = NEW.idUsers;  
END 
// 
DELIMITER ;
```

В чес проблема?

Answer (score 2):

В сообщении об ошибке говорится, что нельзя иметь два триггера на одной таблице, которые срабатывают на одно событие. Сделайте один триггер BEFORE INSERT, если это соответствует логике.

Или поместите весь код в один триггер.

Comment: поместить код в один тригер - можно подробности

Comment: spasibo, vopros rewen

Comment: Если вы покажете тот другой триггер для "Trigger 2" ( на таблице users), то я смогу дать вам и подробности. :-)